# iOS simulator not showing content with Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6.3

I am using Xcode 6.3

I added textfield into the storyboard file.

Its showing in the MainStoryboard Preview.

But getting blank screen, when i am running app using IOS simulator.

Please give me suggestion so that i can resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you set constraints etc?

Comment: No, i have not set constraints. Is contraints required ?

Comment: If frame is outside of bounds of superview you will not see it

Comment: yes thanks its working, when i add contraints in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `frame` is outside of `bounds` of its `superview` you will not see it. So you need to set appropriate `constraints` to your `viewController`